# Is "hot sun" grammatically correct?

Tags: word-usage

Can we use the term 'HOT SUN'. I am always confused if the term 'hot' can be used with sun. Eg: I don't want to go out in this hot sun.

Comment: Hi Ninni, welcome to ELU! I understand completely why you are asking this question. The answer is "Yes!" it's perfectly correct.

Comment: It's those cold January suns that put me off going outside. There's just *no* heat in them.

Answer (score 6):

"I don't want to go out in this hot sun" is a perfectly acceptable and grammatical English sentence.  Hot is simply an adjective describing the effects of the sun.

Comment: However, if you're talking about the star then it could be a pleonasm, which is a form of tautology - i.e. a construct that repeats the same idea to put more stress on it (the spaceship plunged into the hot sun). That is, unless you are comparing it to other stars, in which case it could be relatively hot compared to all the others.

Answer (score 3):

What makes the sentence correct is what the word "sun" really means.

The usual definition refers to the actual entity, the star in the middle of our solar system.

The definition of "sun" here does not refer to the star but rather the intensity of heat and light that the sun casts over the environment.

Therefore, it is perfectly logical to say "hot sun" due to the fact that you are commenting on the ambient heat rather than the actual star.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is YES, it is the right choice. "I don't want to go out in this hot sun" is perfectly gramatical and current usage.

Hot - adj - capable of giving a sensation of heat or of burning.

> In addition to "sun", "hot" (specifically meaning "having a high temperature") is often used with several other nouns:
>
> - hot dog
> - hot weather
> - hot bath
> - hot dinner
> - hot drink
> - hot oven

Hot (adj) can also be used in several contexts (formal, informal or slang) where it has completely different meanings. You'll find most of them at http://www.thefreedictionary.com/hot